# Is the following a surjective function on a boxed codomain?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, elementary-functions

Naive question, but my mind cannot reason today. Say I have the following function

$$f(x): \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1] ~~~~~~~~~~~ f(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$$

The function is

$\Box\ $ Injective and Surjective

$\Box\ $ Injective but not Surjective

$\Box\ $ Not injective but Surjective

$\Box\ $ Neither Injective nor surjective

This is my reasoning: for a function to be surjective, we need its codomain to coincide with its image. The codomain here is $[0, 1]$.

The image of the function $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$, right? Or shall I have to consider what is its image "inside" the codomain I have?

In this case I would hence say the function is injective but not surjective.

Please just tell me if I'm right of if I said a load of nonsenses...

**Add**

I do also know that surjective means the codomain equals the domain  of its inverse. Here the inverse is $-\ln(1-x)$ whose domain is $x < 1$, hence they do not coincide since the codomain is $[0,1]$. Right?

Comment: While MathFail's answer shows you that $1$ is not attainable as an image, I would also like to point out that $f: \mathbb R \to [0,1] $ is not definable. As $x \to -\infty, f(x) \to -\infty $ as well. $-\infty$ is decidedly *not* part of your codomain.

Comment: Your image must always be contained in the codomain. That function is not a function.

Comment: @DavidReed Ah, so that this question makes no sense. Then there is an error in the exercises sheet. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidReed Suppose there was a misprint, like $f$ is actually defined $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Would in that case the function be injective but not surjective?

Comment: Yes, that is likely what was intended, and that would be the correct answer.

Comment: Other possibility: the domain was supposed to be $\mathbb R_+=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injective:

$$f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow1-e^{-x}=1-e^{-y}\Rightarrow e^{-x}=e^{-y}\Rightarrow -x=-y\Rightarrow x=y$$

Not Surjective:

Because for $1\in[0,1]$, there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$1-e^{-x}=1\Leftrightarrow e^{-x}=0$$

So the function is not surjective.